# How do I access Google Drive Application Data from a remote server?

Tags: google-oauth, google-drive-api

For my application I want the user to be able to store files on Google Drive and for my service to have access to these same files created with the application.

I created a Client ID for web application and was able to upload/list/download files from JavaScript (client side) with drive.appfolder scope. This is good, this is half of what I want to do.

Now I want to access the same files from Node.js (server side). I am lost as to how to do this. Do I create a new Client ID for the server? (if so, how will the user authenticate?) Do I pass the AuthToken my user got client-side and try to use that on the server? I don't think this will work as the AuthToke is time-sensitive (and probably not intended to be used from multiple IPs).

Any direction or example server-side code will be helpful. Again, all I want is to access these same files the user created with my application, not any other files in the user's Google Drive.

CLARIFICATION: I think my question boils down to: "Is it possible to access the same Application Data on Google Drive both client-side and server-side?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do I create a new Client ID for the server?**

Up to you. You don't need to, but you can. See below.

**if so, how will the user authenticate?**

Up to you. OAuth is about authorisation, not authentication.
Just in case you meant authorisation, the user authorises the Project, which may contain multiple client IDs.

**Do I pass the AuthToken my user got client-side and try to use that on the server?**

You can do, but not a good idea for the reason you state. The preferred approach is to have a separate server Client ID, and use that to request offline access, which returns (eventually) a Refresh Token, which you store in your server. You then use that Refresh Token to request Access Tokens whenever you need them.

**AuthToken is ... (and probably not intended to be used from multiple IPs).**

It is **not** bound to a specific IP address

**Is it possible to access the same Application Data on Google Drive both client-side and server-side?"**

Yes

Most of what you need is at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score 0):

Getting Google Drive access working from a remote server can be tricky, but it's definitely possible with some configuration. Here are the key steps I'd recommend:

- Create a Google Drive API app credential in Desktop App mode through
  the Google Cloud Console:
  https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

  - Go to the Credentials page and click "Create Credentials"
  - Choose "OAuth client ID"
  - Select "Desktop app" as the Application type (Here it is some part of the trick!)
  - Give your app a name. Click "Create".
  - On the resulting dialog, click "Download JSON" to download your client secret file (client_secret_really_long_ID.json)
- Upload this JSON to your remote server's workspace.
- In your local machine, setup
  an SSH tunnel between your local machine and the remote server. This
  tunnels traffic so you can authenticate locally while the code runs
  on the remote server. Keep the terminal running until you finally log in through Google OAuth pop up window:

  ```bash
  ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000 [server-username]@[server-public-IP]
  ```
- In your Python code, use
  the PyDrive library (https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive2/) and connect
  specifying localhost and the port for your SSH tunnel. Click in the link that appears. This will
  redirect the auth popup to your local machine:

```py
from pydrive2.auth import GoogleAuth 
from pydrive2.drive import GoogleDrive

path_to_secrets_file = 'client_secrets_json'
gauth = GoogleAuth.DEFAULT_SETTINGS['client_config_file'] = path_to_secrets_file 
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth(port_numbers=[5000], 
                         launch_browser=False) # important to use the same port as the used in the tunnel
```

- Authenticate with a
  Google account you gave Drive access to in the Cloud Console. The
  auth callback will go through the tunnel back to your code.
- You can
  now access Drive files and data using PyDrive in your remote Python
  scripts! See the PyDrive quickstart:
  https://iterative.ai/docs/pydrive/quickstart