# Google Drive API accessing both "online" and "offline" at the same time

Tags: google-oauth, google-drive-api

This is a follow up to my previous question: [How do I access Google Drive Application Data from a remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686601/how-do-i-access-google-drive-application-data-from-a-remote-server/26689016#26689016)

I have an application which needs to access Google Drive AppFolder both client-side (online, JavaScript) and server-side (offline, Python). My application is unique in that the client and the server may not be able to communicate past the original authentication.

Thus, I use the following to obtain an auth token for the server (initiated client-side):

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES,
        'access_type': 'offline',
        'response_type': 'code',
        'state': 'my_state',
        }, null, 2),
        'redirect_uri': 'http://server/oauth2callback',
        'immediate': false
    },
    handleOfflineAuthResult);
```

the server stores the credentials including refresh token.

Then the client (in a subsequent user session) sends requests directly to Google Drive for token:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
                    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                    'scope': SCOPES,
                    'immediate': true
                }, handleAuthResult);
```

now when the client does that <strike>it gets a refresh token but invalidates the refresh_token for the server</strike>. Thus my server can no longer refresh its token and gets 'AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant'.

Is there any way to solve this problem assuming the client and the server cannot communicate past the original authentication (i.e. the client can't just ask the server for its auth_token, that's by design) ?

The only "solution" I have thought of is to have the client store its auth_token and refresh_token in the AppFolder and the server continuously pull the AppFolder for new credentials, subsequently replacing its copy with the client one.

Comment: Is the client id the same for both?  you can have up to 30 refresh-tokes for each Client_id / user combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> when the client does that [calls gapi.auth.authorize] it gets a refresh token but invalidates the
>   refresh_token for the server

At least the first part is incorrect, and I suspect the second part is too. gapi.auth.authorize returns an **access token**, not a refresh token (see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#OAuth20TokenObject).

I doubt very much that requesting an access token for your client is invalidating a refresh token for your server. If you are 100% sure that it is, you should use a separate client ID for each of your JS and web client apps. Note that a JS client will never use a refresh token, as this would be a major security flaw. JS clients always request access tokens as needed, either from your server or from Google.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I missed the part that Google sends the refresh token only the first time the user authenticates with the app. Thus, although the process appeared to work, Google was not sending a refresh_token during the exchange, thus my server never really had a refresh_token. I solved it by adding 'approval_prompt':'force' to the request for offline access, which  ensures a refresh_token will be send. I also started using two different IDs for JS and offline. Thanks!